# LiPo battery charging pcb

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I am looking for a 3.7V LiPo battery circuit that will handle  over-voltage protection along with charging and 3.7V to 5V boost. I've found this popular pcb on ebay:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-x-PCB-Li-ion-Lipo-Battery-3-7V-step-up-Convert-to-Output-Power-DC-5V-DLX-UPDC-/130725341903?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e6fd66acf#

It seems to cover all that I need but I can't tell if it steps down the charging voltage or if I have to provide it with a regulated 3.7V supply to charge the battery with? I can tell that one IC is an 8205A which provides all the over/under protection features but I can't read the numbers on the other ICs to look up data sheets. Is there a sure way to tell if this pcb has this feature or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That board has no charging functions at all. It will provide over-voltage protection, and will give 5 volts out, but any charger is entirely separate.